# How to debug "Heroku worker=x PID:x timeout (31s > 30s), killing"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku is showing me following error.

All other things are working fine. When I will click on a specific link this will give me following error. Actually there are are calculation on backend when I click.

```
2016-06-25T15:14:30.617859+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2016-06-25T15:14:30.617743 #3] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:1111 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
2016-06-25T15:14:30.653341+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2016-06-25T15:14:30.653226 #3] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 1111 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
2016-06-25T15:14:30.667735+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-06-25T15:14:30.667572 #1374]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

Answer (score 0):

It means the page is taking more than 30 seconds to respond (which is a lot) and Heroku is killing the process.

Either optimize the page (e.g. using some form of caching, pre-calculation, AJAX, ...) or move off the calculation to a background job.